# How to receive the current mouseposition when moved over an SVG object?

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, dom-events, mousemove

I have a div with many SVG objects in it.

```
<div id="outerDiv">
 <div id="widget1">
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
 </div>
 <div id="widget2">
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
 </div>
 <div id="widget3">
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
 </div>
...
</div>
```

How can I receive the current mouseposition, when the cursor is over one of those SVG object?

Sidenote: without extern libs like D3, Snap ... only jQuery allowed.

This doesn't work, because **I don't receive any mousemove event when I move over the SVG object**.

```
var mousemoveHandler = function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("doc.mousemove: " + event.pageX + " " + event.pageY);
};
$(document).on("mousemove", mousemoveHandler);
```

Furthermore, a mousemove handler on an SVG element (e.g. invisible g-element) returns only the relative mouseposition.

**edit:**
The SVG objects don't have any event handlers which might stop the event propagation.

Comment: event.clientX; event.clientY?

Comment: The problem is, that i dont receive any event when i move over the SVG... so clientX and clientY wont work either.

Comment: Make the SVG an image if you want to handle the mouse outside it (i.e. in the parent document). Otherwise handle the mouse within the SVG document itself.

Comment: i cant handle the mouse inside the svg doc because i want to implement a multi selection (with mousdown+mousemove+mouseup events).

Comment: try adding the style pointer-events: none to the object tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SVG elements within your object elements are handling all the mouse events. You can turn this off by adding the style pointer-events: none to the object tags.

Answer (score 0):

Your event `mousemoveHandler` is never triggered. 
use instead

```
$('object').hover(mousemoveHandler);
```

If this doesn't work, you can add a class onto your widgets and bind on the class.

EDIT:

```
    <div id="outerDiv">
 <div id="widget1">
     <object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
 </div>
 <div id="widget2">
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
 </div>
 <div id="widget3">
   <object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>
 </div>
...
</div>
```

properly html code is closed with another tag.

change `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"/>`
to `<object type="image/svg+xml" data="my.svg"></object>`

Comment: its binded to the doc...so it gets triggered everytime i move the mouse over the whole doc. But it doesnt work when i enter one of the svg objects.

Comment: my fault...shortened the source code too much. its proper html :-)

Comment: nope...it is proper html, i just shortened the sourcecode here too much.

Comment: which browser do you use?
Chrome and this link works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/p4vwgcym/
I didn't check other browsers